# Raspberry Pi 3で「5 Enable Camera」の選択肢が無い。

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Raspberry Pi 3で「5 Enable Camera」の選択肢が表示されません。
Pi3では「5 Enable Camera」の選択肢は無いのがデフォルトなのでしょうか。

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

でOSの更新をしたり、再起動したりしましたが、やはり表示されません。

手元の画面では、「5 Interfacing Options」→「P1 Camera」から有効化の是否が選択できるようですが…。ここが「5 Enable Camera」とイコールと考えてよいのでしょうか。

簡単なところと思いますが、調べてもわからずで詰まっております。
どなたか教えていただけますととても助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: raspbianのzipファイルの正確なファイル名を教えていただけますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2017/05現在、raspi-configでカメラを有効にする場合は下記のメニューを順番に選択します。
>   5 Interfacing Options - Configure connections to peripher
>   P1 Camera - Enable/Disable connection to the
>   Would you like the camera interface to be enabled? - 
>   Would you like to reboot now? -

とのことなので、そちらで良いようですよ。

http://www.neko.ne.jp/~freewing/raspberry_pi/raspberry_pi_3_camera_setup/